# How to reduce system lag in dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

How to reduce System Lag from Dataflow streaming job?

Job details -
Machine Type - n1-highmem-2 ,
num_workers - 120 ,
max_num_workers - 120,
region - us-central1,
worker_zone - us-central1-a

System lag at the start of the job is usually under 20 sec, as the job time increases the system lag starts to creep up max upto an hour i.e. 60 minutes.

Tried troubleshooting the code whether something is stuck while processing the messages but everything seems to be fine.

Are there any specific metrics we need to check which will give us hint on why this system lag is increasing and how can we know more about this lag and why it is occuring?

Comment: Often times it is indeed some processing element that's stuck. There are options to profile the application such as https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/profiling-a-pipeline. Also, Dataflow UI contains a lot of metrics that may be useful (CPU, memory, throughput, lateness/watermark). From your description it may be hard to rule out. What IOs are you using?

Comment: Thanks Bruno for providing this info, will try this and hopefully will get some information which will be helpful!

Comment: Also, I am using Apache beam for windowing , below is the code for the same -
WindowInto(FixedWindows(10), trigger=Repeatedly(AfterAny(AfterCount(20),AfterProcessingTime(10))),accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING, allowed_lateness=10)

Am I missing something in this? as my pipeline is running fine but System lag starts to increase slowly also watermark gets stuck. Not sure if above code is the issue or not.

Comment: I would look at the transforms/sinks to be honest. Assuming windows / group by key results aren't too large / doesn't have any specific hotkeys. This may be helpful https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/writing-dataflow-pipelines-with-scalability-in-mind